# use GNU parallel to parallelize a multi-threaded command

Tags: python, multithreading, gnu-parallel

I just wrote a python script which involves multi-threading, something like:

```
    python myScript.py -cpu_n 5 -i input_file
```

To run the command for my hundreds of input files, I am generating a list (commands.list) of commands for each one:

```
    python myScript.py -cpu_n 5 -i input_file1
    python myScript.py -cpu_n 5 -i input_file2
    python myScript.py -cpu_n 5 -i input_file3
    ...
```

And I'm trying to schedule them with the command 'parallel' and 10 CPUs of three different machines:

```
   parallel -S 10/$server1 -S 10/$server2 -S 10/$server3 < commands.list
```

My question is: what is the max number of CPUs will be used on each server with the parallel command? Will it be 5*10=50 or just 10 cpus?

Comment: Hard to say without any code.

Comment: Firstly, be careful to differentiate *CPUs* from *cores*, a single CPU may have 8 or more cores. Secondly, you need to be careful about *jobs* and *cores* - you could create one job that might wander around and get executed on different cores at different times - think *"CPU/core affinity"*. One job could, theoretically run on each of the 10 CPUs at some stage in its life.

Comment: If the commands.list is so simple, you might simply have GNU Parallel generate it: parallel python myScript.py -cpu_n 5 -i ::: input_file*; If the command is very complex, use a bash function: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Calling-Bash-functions

Answer (score 2):

From `man parallel`:

```
   --jobs N
   -j N
   --max-procs N
   -P N     Number of jobslots on each machine. Run up to N
            jobs in parallel.  0 means as many as possible.
            Default is 100% which will run one job per CPU
            core on each machine.


   -S
   [@hostgroups/][ncpu/]sshlogin[,[@hostgroups/][ncpu/]sshlogin[,...]]
   :
            GNU parallel will determine the number of CPU
            cores on the remote computers and run the number
            of jobs as specified by -j.  If the number ncpu
            is given GNU parallel will use this number for
            number of CPU cores on the host. Normally ncpu
            will not be needed.
```

So your command will run up to 10 jobs on each server in parallel.

Whether each of your commands will use 5 CPU cores is unclear. If each of your commands use 5 cores, 50 cores per server will be used, and in this case I will recommend you do not use the `ncpu/server` syntax, but instead use:

```
parallel -j 20% -S $server1,$server2,$server3 < commands.list
```

This way you can mix servers that have different number of cores, and GNU Parallel will start 1/5th of that in parallel.

Comment: I do agree that the percentage should be included. Interesting was that I just tried in a smaller scale: a python script using 2 cpus and a prallel command with 2 cpus on three servers respectively. The result was that each server only provide 2 cpus but not 2*2 cpus.